# Does crosswalk/xwalk embedded runtime support Adobe flash content on Android?

Tags: android, flash, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk-project

I want to support Adobe Flash content playback in my Android application. I want to know if I can get Flash content working with XWalk runtime in my Android application ? Gecko view is an alternative but there is no official support for Flash.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, Adobe Flash does not support in Crosswalk.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Crosswalk Project does not support Flash.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alexis Menard and @Honry mentioned, It indeed doesn't support flash.

Unfortunately, Flash is not supported on Android since 4.1.

You can try installing the **Flash Player APK**. But I am not sure it will work the same on all android devices.